Techniques or mantras to make you mind less distracted?
Today My mom asked me to bring sweets and flowers for puja, but I forgot to bring the sweets. This happens most of the days and I am afraid I am very much distracted . This small thing shows that at important times to I will forget my objectives . How can one improve on this part of our lives - to not being distracted and be fully focused?  Are there any mantras to make me focused for some time and detached after that? Thank you.
